# trying to add two BigInterger Numbers together in a class Constructor and gettiing stackoverflow error

Tags: java

trying to add two BigInterger Numbers together in a class Constructor and gettiing stackoverflow error.
import java.math.BigInteger;

```
public class BigNumber implements Cloneable {

    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    BigInteger sum2 = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

    BigNumber(String g) {
        sum = sum.add(new BigInteger(g));
    }

    public String ToString() {
        String a = "" + sum;
        return a;
    }

    public Object CloneNumber() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    public BigNumber add(BigNumber other) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return ((BigNumber) BigNumber.this.CloneNumber()).add(other);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        BigNumber g = new BigNumber("46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538");
        BigNumber j = new BigNumber("37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250").add(g);
        String f = j.ToString();
        System.out.print(f);
    }

}
```

Comment: its a self created method??

Comment: Removed my comment. You shoul still change the name to toString() if you want to override the proper method. Here it's very bad practice.

Comment: You call `add` inside `add`...

Comment: oh thanks alot for your feedback?, my first ever program experimenting with bigInts and I'm baffled??

Comment: stackoverflow exception?

Comment: add is a methid name and add is the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack overflow isn't in your constructor. It's when your `main` method calls `add` on your `BigNumber`.

This is the first problem:

```
public BigNumber add(BigNumber other) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return ((BigNumber) BigNumber.this.CloneNumber()).add(other); 
}
```

You're calling `add` within the `add` method... how would you expect that to work?

It's not clear why you've got both `sum` and `sum2`, but I expect your `add` method only needs to be:

```
public BigNumber add(BigNumber other) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return new BigNumber(sum.add(other.sum).toString());
}
```

... although you'd be better off with an overload of the constructor to accept a `BigInteger`, at which point you can just have:

```
public BigNumber add(BigNumber other) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return new BigNumber(sum.add(other.sum));
}
```

The constructors (and field declaration) would then look like this:

```
// Personally I'd make the class final, but that's a different matter
public class BigNumber {
    private final BigInteger value; // Renamed from sum - see below

    public BigNumber(BigInteger value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public BigNumber(String value) {
        this(new BigInteger(value));
    }

    ... methods ...
}
```

Additionally:

- You should override the existing `toString` method rather than introducing your own `ToString` method
- You should override `clone()` instead of introducing your own `CloneNumber` method
- Follow Java naming conventions, where methods are camelCased, not PascalCased.
- You should remove the `sum2` field which isn't used anywhere within your class
- You don't need to add anything in your constructor - you can just have:

  ```
  this.sum = new BigInteger(g);
  ```
- Your field is called `sum` but it's not obviously the sum of anything - it's just the value. I would rename it to `value` or something similar.
- It's not clear why you're doing this at all - you're just reproducing a small part of the `BigInteger` class... why?

Comment: it conflicts with my constructor and sum2 is unused at this point

Comment: @user3255780: What do you mean by "it conflicts with my constructor"? (Note that I changed the constructor call within `add` to call `toString` on the `BigInteger` first, but I've also said that you should have a constructor accepting a `BigInteger`.)

Comment: @user3255780: No, you should have two constructors - one of which probably delegates to the other. I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: hi yes you solved the problem. Thanks alot and thanks for being patient with me

Comment: Oh i see what you did there..thanks alot for your help. As soon at it lets me i will mark your answer. Thanks

Comment: one more question other.sum why did you have to link the constructor with the Biginteger in this wa?

Comment: @user3255780: I didn't *have* to - it's just cleaner that way. Typically I have one "primary constructor" which everything else chains to. That way if you have something that you need to validate, you only need to do it in one place.